# PHP Get method not taking

Tags: php, get, space

I have used `Get` method in a form to fetch the name variable from a page, but it's only fetching the firstname and leaving the part after space. I want to select the complete field along with spaces.

```
<a href=view_contsheet.php?Patientid=<?php echo $_GET["id"]; ?>&Patientname=<?php echo $_GET["Patientname"];?>>View Visits</a>
```

In this link, only the first name is getting passed. How can I concat the complete field?

Answer (score 3):

This might be because spaces are not allowed in URLs.

```
<a href="view_contsheet.php?Patientid=<?php echo $_GET["id"]; ?>&Patientname=<?php echo urlencode($_GET["Patientname"]);?>">View Visits</a>
```

`urlencode()` will make the parameter url-friendly.
There is also a `urldecode()` function, which does the reverse of `urlencode()`

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
<a href="view_contsheet.php?Patientid=<?php echo $_GET["id"]; ?>&Patientname=<?php echo urlencode($_GET["Patientname"]);?>">View Visits</a>
```

and at the next page use `urldecode`

Comment: put quotes around your href value!

Comment: You're encoding the wrong parameter (id instead of Patientname)

Answer (score 0):

As I see it you shouldn't send the patient's name at all in the url.

Instead of

```
<a href=view_contsheet.php?Patientid=<?php echo $_GET["id"];?>&Patientname=<?php echo $_GET["Patientname"];?>>View Visits</a>
```

do

```
<a href="view_contsheet.php?Patientid=<?php echo $_GET["id"]; ?>">View Visits</a>
```

and in view_contsheet.php you fetch the name based on the Patientid

```
$id = $_GET['Patientid'];
"select Patientname FROM patients WHERE Id=$id"....
```